# How can I list the products in the category with Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm using `Laravel 8` Framework. My database is like this:

**categories**

**`id - name - category_url`**

**products**

**`id - category_id - products_name - products_url`**

Database Relationship: **`categories->id == products->category_id`**

My question: How can I list the products in the category?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a define a reverse relationship between the two as well. In your Product model, you have to define a belongsTo relationship and then you can get the list of products for each category.

Answer (score 1):

You define your relation in category model like below

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'category_id');
}
```

And finally in controller you can use with()

```
Category::with('products')->get();
```

Comment: @Mert If your relation is one to one then you can use hasOne instead of hasMany. Now you can find your products in relation.

Comment: Thanks Khusal Berva. But I can not list with Blade. model and controller is ok. my blade.php very basic. @foreach($products as $urun)

{!!$urun->baslik!!}

@endforeach

How can I improve the code?

Comment: @Mert can you please share dd() result of your get query? so i can help you in detail